# Validating the shape of Ruby hashes?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

A longer, alternative phrasing of the question is: "What are some Ruby libraries or approaches to test the shape of arbitrary data structures (hashes, arrays, integers, floats, strings, and so on)?"

To start, let me show a simple example:

```
hash_1 = {
  k1: 1.0,
  k2: 42,
  k3: {
    k4: "100.00",
    k5: "dollars"
  }
}
```

Next, I want to validate it -- by this I mean compare against a shape / schema / template such as:

```
shape_a = {
  k1: Float,
  k2: Integer,
  k3: Hash
}
```

Or, perhaps, a more specific shape:

```
shape_b = {
  k1: Float,
  k2: Integer,
  k3: {
    k4: String,
    k5: String
  }
}
```

One possible API might look like:

```
require '_____________'

hash_1.schema = shape_a
hash_1.valid? # => true

hash_1.schema = shape_b
hash_1.valid? # => true
```

These are just examples, I'm open to other approaches.

About 3 years ago, I wrote [schema_hash](http://rubygems.org/gems/schema_hash) to scratch my own itch. I plan to update it, but first I wanted to get a sense for alternatives and better approaches.

The motivation for this question comes from a Mongo use case, but the question is not necessarily Mongo specific.

Like I mentioned at the top, I would like to see or build the ability validate arbitrary data structures: hashes, arrays, primitives, and so on, in any nested combination.

#### "You don't need a schema for Mongo, so why do you care?"

- Like I mention above, I am not *exclusively* thinking about Mongo use cases
- But even in the context of Mongo, even if you don't want to *require* a data structure to take a certain shape, it still can be useful to test a data structure against a shape or pattern and act accordingly.

#### "Why not just write custom validations?"

When I worked on a previous project, this is exactly where I started. It got to be painful to write validations repeatedly for nested hashes. I started thinking about what would make it easier, and I came up with a syntax similar to what I shared above.

#### What is out there? What should I try?

All of this said, I'm curious about what other people are doing. Is there a "golden path"? I'm  trying out different approaches, including embedded documents and validates_associated with [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html) for example... but those approaches seem like overkill when hashes get nested more than a level or so deep.

I looked around for [Validation on Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=validation) for validation (pun intended), but didn't find what I was looking for. While I was there, I suggested a new category called "Validation."

It is quite possible that what I'm asking fits less in the "validation" topic area and more in others, such as "data structures" and "traversals". If so, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: I don't want to anchor this conversation too much around a particular API and code that I put together -- I'm more interested in alternatives -- but in case it is useful to compare, here are two core parts of the `schema_hash` gem: [schemable.rb](https://github.com/djsun/schema_hash/blob/master/lib/schemable.rb) and [traversable.rb](https://github.com/djsun/schema_hash/blob/master/lib/traversable.rb)

Comment: Regarding the golden path, five years on: there are now many "nested model" approaches out there worth checking out, among them Disposable, ArDocStore, dry-types, and the Rails 5 attribute API.

The idea is that you treat the embedded document as something higher-level and more constrained than a hash. Validation is part of this, but it's not the only part. One might also benefit from representing the hash as a tree of objects with accessor methods, from type coercion, and and from being able to reuse document shapes, among other things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** Rereading your question my answer seems a bit too simplistic. I'll leave it up to your wether I should delete it or not, just let me know through a comment.

A very simple approach would be this:

```
class Hash
  def has_shape?(shape)
    all? { |k, v| shape[k] === v }
  end
end
```

Use like this:

```
hash_1.has_shape?(shape_a) #=> true
shape_b = { k1: Float, k2: Integer, k3: Integer }
hash_1.has_shape?(shape_b) #=> false
```

This already seems to be taking care of your first described version quite well. It wouldn't be hard to factor this out into a lib so it doesn't monkey-patch `Hash`. Adding recursion to the `has_shape?` method will take care of your more elaborate case.

**Update:** Here's a version with recursion:

```
class Hash
  def has_shape?(shape)
    all? do |k, v|
      Hash === v ? v.has_shape?(shape[k]) : shape[k] === v
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This isn't a bad start, but (as you allude to) it doesn't handle nested shapes. Also, I'm not asking people to write new code for me --- unless you really want to :) -- I'm really just hoping to find what is already out there.

Comment: Here's a version that does handle nested shapes, I went ahead and added it to my library of random additions to Ruby: https://github.com/citizen428/shenanigans/blob/master/lib/shenanigans/hash/has_shape_pred.rb The whole lib is on Rubygems.org if you are so inclined.

Comment: I haven't run that against various test cases, but it looks clean and covers the example I gave. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I wanted to add something: validation of hashes, depending on what you want, might mean: (1) are all required keys present and do they have valid values? (2) are no extra keys present? In the code I wrote, I wanted to check that both were satisfied, which added some complexity.

Comment: Glad this was at least somewhat useful. As far as I can tell my solution covers (1) and (2) since extra keys will return `nil` for `shape[k]`, so the `all?` won't be satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you're looking for:

https://github.com/JamesBrooks/hash_validator

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Rails and want to validate only the keys, you can use `assert_valid_keys`:

```
{ name: 'Rob', years: '28' }.assert_valid_keys(:name, :age) # => raises "ArgumentError: Unknown key: :years. Valid keys are: :name, :age"
{ name: 'Rob', age: '28' }.assert_valid_keys('name', 'age') # => raises "ArgumentError: Unknown key: :name. Valid keys are: 'name', 'age'"
{ name: 'Rob', age: '28' }.assert_valid_keys(:name, :age)   # => passes, raises nothing
```

https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/assert_valid_keys

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a gem for validating hash like data http://rubygems.org/gems/validates_simple and it is easy to add validation that will check if the values is a member of a class. As for validating nested values i will have to update the gem to support this if needed. Adding the rule is as simple as

```
  module Validation
    module Rules
      def validates_is_a_member_of(field, class, message='')
         callback = lambda do |data|
           data[field].is_a? Class
         end
         validates(field, callback, message)
      end
    end
  end
```

After that you can just do validator.validates_is_a_member_of('age', Integer, 'age must be an int') and do validator.validate({'age': 232423})

Answer (score 1):

Seems like [Schemacop](https://github.com/sitrox/schemacop) would have been an ideal fit for this occasion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slight tweak to Michael Kohl's recursive has_shape? method that will work for both shape_a and shape_b (added a test to check if the shape has a sub-hash to recurse to):

```
  def has_shape?(shape)
    all? do |k, v|
      (Hash === v && Hash === shape[k]) ? v.has_shape?(shape[k]) : shape[k] === v
    end
  end
```

Also, FWIW I find is_a? more readable than ===. E.g.:

```
  def has_shape?(shape)
    all? do |k, v|
      (v.is_a?(Hash) && shape[k].is_a?(Hash)) ? v.has_shape?(shape[k]) : v.is_a?(shape[k])
    end
  end
```

However, if your shape is JSON-compatible then you might want to consider the [Ruby JSON Schema Validator](https://github.com/ruby-json-schema/json-schema). It is more heavyweight and verbose, but you can use it to validate a hash as well as JSON and it gives you more control (e.g. required keys, optional keys, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that uses a list of expressions:

```
class Hash
  def has_shape?(shape)
    all? do |key, value|
      if value.is_a? Hash
        value.has_shape?(shape[key])
      else
        shape[key].all? { |expression| expression.call(value) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
shape = {
  type: [
    -> (type) { type.is_a? String },
    -> (type) { !type.blank?  },
    -> (type) { %(text number).include? type }
  ]
}

{ type: "text" }.has_shape? shape # => true
```

With this you should be able to very dynamically ensure a shape of your hash.

UPDATE:

With this version you are not able to check if a key/value pair is missing, because we are asking all? from the hash we are calling the method on. This results in all? only iterating over keys/values that exists on that hash.

I've updated the implementation to respect the "target" hash for comparison. Now the has_shape? method successfully determines missing key/value pairs.

```
class Hash
  def has_shape?(shape)
    shape.all? do |key, _|
      if self[key.to_s].is_a? Hash
        self[key.to_s].has_shape?(shape[key])
      else
        shape[key].all? { |expression| expression.call(self[key.to_s]) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```